# I have questions about ListView and SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am a beginner developer who is studying Android.

The function I want to develop is "Save the data entered in EditText as JSON, save it as SharedPreference, and output it to ListView".

To save it as SharedPreference is OK, but, To output it to ListView is not working now.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private Button save_btn;
private ArrayList<List> data = new ArrayList<List>();

ListAdapter adapter;

String title="";
String info="";
int img = R.drawable.man;

String jsondata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    loadArrayList(getApplicationContext());

    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(listView);


    save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View dlgview = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.adds, null);

            //adds.xml
            final EditText et_title = (EditText) dlgview.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final EditText et_info = (EditText) dlgview.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            ImageView img1 = (ImageView) dlgview.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            dlg.setTitle("ADD");
            dlg.setView(dlgview);
            dlg.setNegativeButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                    try{
                        jsonObject.put("title", et_title.getText().toString());
                        jsonObject.put("info", et_info.getText().toString());
                        jsonObject.put("image",img);

                        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    jsondata = jsonArray.toString();

                    saveArrayList();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            dlg.setPositiveButton("Cancel",null);
            dlg.show();
        }
    });


}//End of onCreate


private void saveArrayList(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    editor.putString("jsonData", jsondata);
    Log.i("moi","get Data test : " + "jsonData");

    editor.apply();

}


private void loadArrayList(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    int size = sharedPrefs2.getInt("appreciation_size",0);
    String strJson = sharedPrefs2.getString("jsonData", "fail");
    Log.i("moi","get SharedPreferences test : " + strJson);

    if (strJson != "fail")
    {
        try {
            JSONArray response = new JSONArray(strJson);
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonobject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                title   = jsonobject.getString("title");
                Log.i("moi","title test : " + "title");
                info    = jsonobject.getString("info");
                Log.i("moi","info test : " + "info");
                data.add(new List(title, info, img));
            }
            adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, data);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}//End of class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here. *is not working now* is not a useful problem description, and *Please give a lot of advice* is not a specific question. You need to *clearly* explain the problem you're having, and ask a *specific question* related to the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your code:

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in `CreateView`.
I think you set adapter `listview` double.

i hope that helps you.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you just called `loadArrayList()` once in `onCreate()`. That means your data in adapter just changes once.

you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but this method doesn`t call`loadArrayList()`.

so try to save new `json` into data in `onClick()`